# SQL with LIMIT1 returns all records

Tags: sql

I made a mistake and entered:

`SELECT * FROM table LIMIT1`

instead of

`SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 1` (note the space between `LIMIT` and `1`)

in the CLI of MySQL. I expected to receive some kind of parse error, but I was surprised, because the query returned all of the records in the table. My first thought was "stupid MySQL, I bet that this will return error in PostgreSQL", but PostgreSQL also returned all records. Then tested it with SQLite - with the same result.

After some digging, I realized that it doesn't matter what I enter after the table. As long as there are no `WHERE/ORDER/GROUP` clauses:

```
SELECT * FROM table SOMETHING -- works and returns all records in table

SELECT * FROM table WHERE true SOMETHING -- doesn't work - returns parse error
```

I guess that this is a standardized behavior, but I couldn't find any explanation why's that. Any ideas?

Comment: You can give any table an alias in a query. This enables you to do self-joins (specify the same table more than once).

Comment: @NikolaMarkovinović Spot on.  The OP has aliased `table` as `LIMIT1` You should post as an answer.

Comment: Suggest the only tag that belongs here is 'sql'

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your first query is equivalent to this query using a table alias:

```
SELECT * FROM yourtable AS LIMIT1
```

The `AS` keyword is optional. The table alias allows you to refer to columns of that table using the alias `LIMIT1.foo` rather than the original table name. It can be useful to use aliases if you wish to give tables a shorter or a more descriptive alias within a query. It is necessary to use aliases if you join a table to itself.

From the [SQL lite documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html):

[image: AS keyword optional]

Comment: Damn, forgot about it. I always use the the 'AS' syntax. I will accept the answer in 10 mins, thanks.

Comment: I hate so much these oradoc kinds of graphics :D

Comment: +1 and I like the graphic too for easy to understand by any novice.

Answer (score 1):

This is why I want DB engine to force the usage of keyword AS for alias names
http://beyondrelational.com/modules/2/blogs/70/posts/10814/should-alias-names-be-preceded-by-as.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM table LIMIT1;
```

`LIMIT1` This has taken as alias by SQL, cause `LIMIT1` is not a reserved literal of SQL.
Something after table name and that is not a reserved keyword always taken as an table alias by SQL.

```
 SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 1;
```

When you used `LIMIT` just after the table name, SQL found that as a reserved keyword and worked for it as per the behavior. IF you want to use reserved key words in query It can be done by putting reserved literals in quotes. like..

```
SELECT * FROM table `LIMIT`;
```

OR

```
SELECT * FROM table `LIMIT 1`;
```

Now all words covered under `` quotes will treated as user defined.
Commonly we did mistake with **date, timestamp, limit etc..** keywords by using them as column names.